# Caffeinated Mac

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, desktop, apple-silicon, ventura

I've just moved to a new M1 Mac Mini. I'm used to keep my Mac on for months, just leaving it in sleep mode when not in use.

I've just realised that this new Mac never really sleeps! It keep waking up every around 15 mins:
[image: CPU activity during the night]

[image: CPU activity in last hour]

I've checked all the settings and, I believe, I disabled all the relative settings (Energy Saver -> Wake for network access, Powernap in past.)

What else can I do to make my Mac sleep when set in sleep mode?

**ADD:** USB plugs are empty and bluetooth is connected to mouse and keyboard. Of course, no direct interaction with devices while sleeping.

[Terminal `pmset -g log` output.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/648trsfqvvnjhcg/Output%20di%20Terminale%20salvato.txt?dl=0)

It's a new Mac set from scratch so basic setup + Dropbox and iStat running background.
Mail, Safari and an RSS reeder running while sleeping. Even closing those 3 apps, same result.

Comment: Does the output of the Terminal.app command `pmset -g log` provide a reason for the waking? USB and Bluetooth devices can be a cause of unintended wake events.

Comment: Added details in question. Terminal provides tons of output.

Comment: Try to run `log show --last boot --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason"` in Terminal to know the cause of it

Answer (score -1):

This is probably linked to when you receive notifications, it turns on to make the notification appear just like an iPhone and then turn off. I suppose you might just turn it off completely if you don't want this to happen. :)